# Teamcity Build Trigger to call a Main method

Tags: maven, teamcity

I'm new to using Teamcity and I would like to do the following on an existing project (Project A) that is built successfully after each commit:

1. Once the project is built successfully, I would like to trigger build another project (Project B) by checking out the source code from SVN
2. Once this Project B is built, I want to call a class that contains the main method

We use Maven for all our builds. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to invoke a main method after build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used the Maven exec plugin and added it as a build step to a project that is continuously tracked.